# not able to use CopyToDataTable in linq for returning dataset

Tags: linq, datatable, linq-to-dataset

how to return a `dataset` from `linq` in .net 3.5?

I have seen in some sites that **CopyToDataTable** method is used but I am not able to use that methos as I cannot find System.data.datatableextensions reference in the ref list.
Please help me out.

Thanks  and regards,
veena

Answer (score 1):

Which also goes for VB.NET, only you have to declare query variable as IEnumerable(Of DataRow) instead putting only Dim keyword.

Answer (score -2):

Copied Directly from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx). Try to search before asking

```
// Fill the DataSet.
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 FillDataSet(ds);

DataTable orders = ds.Tables["SalesOrderHeader"];

IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
    where order.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate") > new DateTime(2001, 8, 1)
    select order;

DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();

bindingSource.DataSource = boundTable;
```